# how do I pass parameters to onclick="window.location" in LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on MVC4
want to set parameter value from Model inside `li onclick window.location`

> Name = MyValue is hard-coded here
>
> How do I set parameter from Model i'm using foreach loop to iterate.

```
<ul class="my_list">
        <li style="position: relative" onclick="window.location='/Mypage?Name=MyValue'">
         </li>
</ul>
```

> onclick is in `li` how can I set my parameter value there ?

Comment: it is working just tested

Comment: but onclick is in `li` how can I set my dynamic parameter value there ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
<ul class="my_list">
  <li style="position: relative" onclick="myFunction(5);">
  </li>
</ul>
```

With Razor like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <li style="position: relative" onclick="myFunction(@(item.SomeProperty));">
    </li>
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(id)
{
    window.location='/Mypage?Name='+id;
}

</script>
```

I am passing 5 but you can pass some variable in it.

Comment: but onclick is in `li` how can I set my parameter value there ?

Comment: what you means actually i did'nt got it

Comment: I want to set value from Model in foreach how can I do it ? In your answer you have set hardcode 5 as value

Comment: you have to simply pass Model Property there instead of 5

Answer (score 1):

Better approach would be if you are using jQuery you can make use of `data-*` attribute of HTML5 provides:

```
<li style="position: relative" data-name="<% yourValue %>" >

$('.my_list li').on('click', function(){
     window.location = '/Mypage?Name=' + $(this).data('name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
window.location='/Mypage?Name=MyValue'
```

to

```
window.location='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = id })'
```

put your parameters in the new section

Comment: but onclick is in `li` how can I set my parameter value there ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate parameter in onClick method:
Here is how:

```
<ul class="my_list">
<%
name = 'myvalue'
%>
        <li style="position: relative" onclick="window.location='/Mypage?Name="&name&"">
         </li>
</ul>
```